# Pod Images showing up as broken image link icon

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I'm trying to implement an image in my page via pods, but when I link the `img` src as the pod field name `{@pod_product_image_exp}`, I get nothing except the broken link icon for image, I took a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcrS1.jpg.

Here's are the various extensions I've tried:

`<img src="{@pod_product_image_exp.get_post_thumbnail_id}">`

`<img src="{@pod_product_image_exp.post_thumbnail_url}">`

`<img src="{@pod_product_image_exp.get_post_thumbnail_url}">`

`<img src="{@pod_product_image_exp._src}">`

`<img src="{@pod_product_image_exp._src.large}">`

The tutorial I'm following is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWD2uQNLxbY&list=PLtaXuX0nEZk9dCVMQRmSptuJ6YdVzMkr5&index=6

But even copying exactly what he does, I get the broken link image.

I've also tried changing the image I'm uploading but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to change the name of the pod field from `pod_product_image_exp` to something else. I'm not sure if it's cause the name started with pod, but something about that initial name I chose refused to work.